# I having trouble with a price function that i working on from a book

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I got this function to run as an if else statement, however when I convert it to function and return statement then it doesn't run. What is the issue ?

```
function calcTot(merchTot) {
    var orderTot;
    var merchTot = prompt("What is your total?");
    var totalCharge = calcTot(79.99);

    if (merchTot >= 100) {
        orderTot = merchTot;
    } else if (merchTot < 50.01) { orderTot = merchTot + 5; } else { orderTot = merchTot + 5 + (.03 * (merchTot - 50)); }
    return orderTot;
    alert(calcTot(79.99));
    //alert(orderTot);
}
```

Comment: and where is the rest of the function?, you just sent and incomplete code

Comment: What do you mean ? I trying to get it to alert . I will look again later when i get home

Comment: `calcTot` where is the definition of this function

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move the alert up one line, above the return statement. Nothing below the return gets executed.